# Access - duplicate parent and sub records after changing foreign key

Tags: ms-access, duplicates, foreign-keys

I have an Access 2016 db with tables like these:

```
Master
------
| ID = PK1 | ... field = value |

Sub1
----
| ID = 1 | MasterID = PK1 | ... field = value |

SubN
----
| ID = 1 | MasterID = PK1 | ... field = value |
| ID = 2 | MasterID = PK1 | ... field = value |
```

I need a method to run on Sub1 that will allow me to create a duplicate of records for PK1 in Sub1, (through) SubN **after** changing the value from PK1 to PK2 e.g. via input value of "PK2" to a pop-up. It's a given that these will be new records containing MasterID = PK2 i.e. none already exist. So the result would be:

```
Master
------
| ID = PK2 | ... field = value |

Sub1
----
| ID = 2 | MasterID = PK2 | ... field = value |

SubN
----
| ID = 3 | MasterID = PK2 | ... field = value |
| ID = 4 | MasterID = PK2 | ... field = value |
```

There is code offered by the new button wizard to duplicate a record, boiling down to:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectRecord
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectRecord
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPaste
```

This results in all MasterID values of the duplicate equaling PK1... Is it possible to change the MasterID (FK) value while leveraging the code above?

Comment: If the `ID` columns are the "PK" columns of tables `Sub1` to `SubN`, then your example differs from the description of what you want. Do you want to `INSERT` copies of the records (all columns named "...field") or to you just want to `UPDATE` the `MasterID` column? I'm asking because in the example, the values of the `ID` column of the Sub-tables remain the same.

Comment: Post edited. I want to insert records that are duplicated and have the 'MasterID' value changed.

Comment: Are you changing the value of `ID` in the `Master` table? How is Referential Integrity configured? Are the `ID` fields in the Sub tables "Automumber" fields?

Comment: I'm not explicitly changing the value of `ID` in the `Master` table, no. The `ID` values in all tables are Autonumbers, yes. The referential integrity (I think) is setup as Link Master Fields and Link Child Fields, which are both set to `MasterID`.

Comment: Well, if referential Integrity is set up, then the value `PK2` has to exist in the `Master` table before the diplicates are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use that code from the wizard and change the `MasterID` on the fly. Also, it copies only the current record.

You have N tables named `Sub1` through `SubN`, so why not create N queries (`qryDupSub1` through `qryDupSubN`) that will create duplicates of the records with `MasterID = [OldMasterID]` and save them with a `MasterID` of `[NewMasterID]`?

The queries could be defined like this (example for `Sub1`) (I use "... field" just as you did):

```
PARAMETERS OldMasterID long, NewMasterID long;
INSERT INTO Sub1 (MasterID, ... field)
SELECT [NewMasterID], ... field
FROM Sub1 WHERE MasterID = [OldMasterID];
```

You can create code that executes all `N` queries in a loop and take the values for the two parameters from controls on the Form (Textboxes `txtOldMasterID` and `txtNewMasterID` in my example):

```
Const N As Integer = 10 ' the number of queries
Dim i As Integer

With CurrentDb
    For i = 1 To N
        With .QueryDefs("qryDupSub" & i)
            !OldMasterID = Me.txtOldMasterID
            !NewMasterID = Me.txtNewMasterID
            .Execute
            .Close
        End With
    Next
End With
```

Comment: This looks right! Based on the reference for [INSERT INTO Access SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834799.aspx) I think this will work and will try it out.

Comment: Oh, I forgot the `Master` table… just create a similar query for the `Master` table and execute it right before the loop.